# Is there a way to share an installation fo the tor browser bundle among multiple users?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, linux

On Linux, I've tried the following, which doesn't work, but illustrates what I want. Unpack the tor-browser in `/usr/local` and make it readable by all users. Create `$HOME/tor-browser/` for each user which contains their own `Data` directory and symlinks back to `/usr/local/tor-browser` for the Browser and Tor directories. Any ideas?

Answer (score 7):

With the way the Tor Browser is currently built, it ships with a dedicated profile prepared in advance. That profile cannot be shared by multiple users. Also, as there is no update mechanism currently, every upgrades mean that the profile recreated from the clean profile shipped by the Tor Browser.

The only safe solution currently is to have have each users manage their own Tor Browser installation — or eventually script the installation and upgrades in a way or another.

Answer (score 0):

I would handle this through the use of VM's with each user having their own desktop instance and then multiple browser profiles is not an issue because it will be separate installs.